# I cannot see any keys returned when I did np.load("filename.npz") then .keys()?

Tags: python, numpy

I did

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1 , 10)
y = np.sin(x)
np.savez('xy_values', x_vals=x, y_vals=y) 
w = np.load('xy_values.npz')
```

But now `w.keys()` gives me the following:

> `KeysView(<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at`

Any ideas?

Comment: `list(w.keys()` - this is Py3 dictionary usage.

Comment: I got `w.keys() => ['y_vals', 'x_vals']`, numpy v. 1.14.5, what version of numpy are you using?

Comment: I have numpy 1.15.4.     And list(w.keys()) worked! Thanks hpaulj!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `w.keys()` returns an iterable object, which gives you access to the keys. This object, however, does not implement the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods, and thus, does not yield a useful output when printing.

Since the object is iterable, you can just iterate the object to print the result as follows.

```
for k in w.keys():
    print(k)
```

The functions `list` and `tuple` can convert any iterable object into a list and a tuple, respectively. Hence,

```
print(list(w.keys()))  # or
print(tuple(w.keys()))
```

prints the desired keys. In an interactive environment, like IPython or Jupyter, you can omit the call to print to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In recent numpy version,

```
list(w.keys())
```

It works! :)

tested numpy version: 1.19.2